# python simple socket client / server example

Tags: python, sockets, streaming

I am trying to explore using sockets in python to stream data with a toy example:

So far,  I created the following code for the server:

```
from socket import *    
import time    

s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)    
s.bind(('', 10000))    
s.listen(5)    

while True:    
    client, addr = s.accept()    
    print('Got a connection from %s' % str(addr))    
    timestr = time.ctime(time.time()) + "\r\n"     
    client.send(timestr.encode('ascii'))               
    client.close()
```

Code for the client:

```
from socket import *    
s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect(('localhost', 10000))
tm = s.recv(1024)
s.close()
print('The time is %s' % tm.decode('ascii'))
```

This works.
Now I would like to transform that code so that the server send a string (no matter what) every second, and the client prints it. (i.e. testing streaming of data).

I have tried things along the lines of :

```
while True:
    client, addr = s.accept()
    print('Got a connection from %s' % str(addr))
    while True:
        timestr = time.ctime(time.time()) + "\r\n"
        client.send(timestr.encode('ascii'))
        time.sleep(1)
    client.close()
```

But with no luck.
Quite frankly I am a bit lost. I looked for such simple example of creating a basic stripped bare streaming example, but I have not found that anything matching my level of unsophistication.

Any pointers hugely appreciated.

Comment: The client won't print anything until it gets 1024 characters. That's going to take a while.

Comment: socket it primitive object and you have to do all on your own. Client doesn't know how many data it will get and when to stop wait for data and display what it get. One method is to use loop which get one byte (and add to string) until you get `\n`. Other method is to send data with constant size which have information how long string it will send - and then client first has to receive data with known size to get information how log string it has to recevie and then use `recv()` with this size.

Comment: @furas Thanks this is helpful. Would you know of a webpage where I could see a simple example of what you describe ?

Comment: I have [some examples on GitHub](https://github.com/furas/python-examples/tree/master/socket/basic) but I don't remeber if they show all described versions.

Comment: [SimpleProtocol](https://github.com/furas/python-examples/tree/master/socket/simple-protocol) shows second method. Sometimes I see people used `pickle` to send data because it may have method to get size of data.

Comment: @furas I understand that the argument of the recv method is the number of bytes the socket accept before returning the packet. **But then why 1024?** (I saw the same in your example). It does not seems to match the length of the string in [your example](https://github.com/furas/python-examples/blob/master/socket/basic/version-1/server.py) and in mine as well (above)

Comment: `1024` because all examples use this value and people repeate it. `1024` is `2**10` so it is `1kb` and it is treated like `1000` in other system  `1kg`, `1km`. With socket you never know how many data will be send but you have to use some value in function `recv()`